# How do I only add the negative numbers in a multiple string input?

Tags: python

I only want to add all the negative numbers in a multiple input string, but I'm stumped on what to do next

```
a,b,c,d = input().split()
a = float(a)
b = float(b)
c = float(c)
d = float(d)
lis = list(a,b,c,d)
```

say I want to input (-30.22, 10.5, -2.2, -1.8). I only want to use -30.22, -2.2, and -1.8 in addition. How can I do that?

Comment: please provide some examples , input , output to debug the problem

Comment: do you want to add them to the list only, or do you want to have the sum of only the negative numbers?

Comment: i want to have the sum of only the negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

You can do the following, using `sum` with a conditional generator expression:

```
nums = [*map(float, input().split())]
# if you really need named variables for the first four
# a, b, c, d, *_ = nums  

neg_sum = sum(n for n in nums if n < 0)
```

or more fanciful:

```
neg_sum = sum(filter(0.0.__gt__, nums))
```

Some docs:

- [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum)
- [`filter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter)
- [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map)

Comment: Although I really like your funcional style approach. Are map & filter functions discoraged in favor of  list comprehensions as they are not ¨pythonic¨ right?

Comment: I would only discourage them  if you have to "force" in a function, e.g. a `lambda` when it really becomes unreadable. But I wouldn't go as far as calling `map/filter` unpythonic in general. But here, with a dunder method being kind of in the middle, I would prefer the generator expression (no comprehension here!), hence the first suggestion.

Comment: Even more dangerous, you cannot use `(0).__gt__` as `int.__gt__` returns `NotImplemented` for `float` arguments! That will fail silently and just produce wrong results.

Answer (score 1):

Here a list comprehension that does what you want. Please consider that we are supposing here that we only have numbers in the input.

```
neg_sum = sum(float(val) for val in input().split() if float(val) < 0)
```

Comment: You could save yourself the second conversion :) `[... if val[0] == "-"]`

Comment: well for a matter of readability it is more clear using the type conversion than accessing first char in string right?  :)
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/80084/is-premature-optimization-really-the-root-of-all-evil

Comment: No doubt :) Still, you could get rid of the spurious in-memory list and the two conversions: `sum(f for val in input().split() if (f := float(val)) < 0)`